# JavaScript - convert to string using array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I got this code from a book and I don't understand how this statement "mm=months[mm]" convert to month name string:

```
function init(){
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");

    var days=["sun","mon","tue","wed","thur","fri","sat"];
    var months=["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun",
    "jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"];

    var now = new Date();

    var yy = now.getFullYear();
    var mm = now.getMonth();
    var dd = now.getDate();
    var dy = now.getDay();

    mm=months[mm];  //convert to month name string
    dy=days[dy];  //convert to month name string

    var str = dy+","+mm","+dd+","+yy;
    panel.innerHTML+="us date string: "+str;
    str = dy+","+dd+" "+mm+","+yy;
    panel.innerHTML+="<br>uk date string: "+str;
}
window.onload=init();
```

My question is this what exactly does the `mm=months[mm]` and `dy=days[dy]` (convert to month or day name string) do. I don't understand how this statement "mm=months[mm]" convert to month name string, when months is an array. Is this just some build in function of an array?

Comment: It doesn't convert. It takes an **index** into an array and returns the corresponding value. Re-using the same variables is confusing. `days[0]` -> "sun", e.g.

Comment: `from the book` I think online free tutorials are very good. But it's just my thought.

Answer (score 2):

`mm` is a number at the beginning of the statement `mm=months[mm]`, so therefore it returns the `mm`th value in the `months` array which is a string. In JavaScript variables are not strictly typed so it then inserts this string into the variable `mm`

Comment: got it now, so basically mm is like 11 which if you put it in the array index would give you december

Answer (score 0):

`mm` is a number from 0-11 that represents the month specific to the date object you retrieved it from. `months` is an array containing the names of all the months. If you say `mm = months[mm]`, you're saying that `mm` equals the string at position `mm` in the `months` array. It's confusing, because they're using the same variable name. It might have been better to do something like this:

```
var mm = now.getMonth();
alert(mm); // will alert 6
var monthName = months[mm]; // will alert July, which is position 7 in the months array
```

The reason `mm` is six is because the months for some reason are 0-indexed, meaning they start at 0 and go to 11; January would be 0, and December 11.

Answer (score 0):

`days` is an array. Given index `dy=0`, `days[dy]` returns `"sun"`, which is the 0th value in the array. Similarly, given index `dy=1`, `days[dy]` returns `"mon"`, which is the 1st value in the array. And so on.

Same concept for `months`.

But the correct answer should be "use some built-in function in Javascript or jQuery". See this [post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) for more details. Rolling your own datetime conversion functions is almost certainly going to come back and bite you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the date is 08 and month is july .

```
var yy = now.getFullYear();   
var mm = now.getMonth();    // month is 7 now
var dd = now.getDate();     // dd is 8 now
var dy = now.getDay();
```

Now,

```
mm=months[mm];
```

means,

`mm = months[7];`

`// in months array, at seventh index we have july,`

so mm is july.

No its not converting but using value from array based on index.

Answer (score 0):

`mm=month[mm]` take the value at the index `mm` (returned by `now.getMonth()`) in the `months` array and puts it in the `mm` variable. That id the same thing for `dy=days[dy]`.

I recognize that the code is badly written. `mm2=month[mm]` and use `mm2` after (instead of the "new" `mm`) should be written instead.

Comment: @Mageek *cough* bullshit *cough* (Although I would use something more descriptive than `mm2`.)

Comment: @Mageek : I totally agree with you but it is **MORE** convinient to understand how the code works. Good practices are important too.

Comment: @air-dex If it were me, I would have written `var mm=months[new Date().getMonth()];` directly :D